# Relative Künneth formula

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X \to X^\prime \to S$ and $Y \to Y^\prime \to S$ be morphisms of schemes. Then we obtain the following diagram.

[image]

Is it true that under suitable conditions, the equation
$$
\mathbf R \varphi_\ast(\mathbf L p^\ast(\mathcal F) \otimes^{\mathbf L} \mathbf L q^\ast(\mathcal G)) \cong \mathbf L p^{\prime, \ast}(\mathbf R f_\ast(\mathcal F)) \otimes^{\mathbf L} \mathbf L q^{\prime, \ast}(\mathbf R g_\ast(\mathcal G))
$$
holds for any $\mathcal F \in \mathbf D_{\mathsf{Coh}}^b(\mathcal O_X)$ and $\mathcal G \in \mathbf D_{\mathsf{Coh}}^b(\mathcal O_Y)$. In other words, if we write $\mathcal F \boxtimes \mathcal G = \mathbf L p^\ast(\mathcal F) \otimes^{\mathbf L} \mathbf L q^\ast(\mathcal G)$, then is it true that $\mathbf R \varphi_\ast(\mathcal F \boxtimes \mathcal G) \cong \mathbf R f_\ast(\mathcal F) \boxtimes \mathbf R g_\ast(\mathcal G)$? If $X^\prime = S = Y^\prime$, then this equation reduces to the Künneth formula in [0FLN](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0FLN).

Comment: A tangential comment for the bounded derived category of contsructible sheaves: If $S$ is the spectrum of a field $k$ and your schemes are of finite type over $k$, then this is true for $D_{ctf}^b(-, A)$, where $A$ is some torsion noetherian ring (see [Lei Fu, Étale cohomology theory, 9.3.5]. The proof in the reference uses the universal strong local acyclicity of finite type $k$-schemes relative to $D_{ctf}^b(-, A)$.

Comment: Maybe I should add, continuing my previous tangential comment, that with proper morphisms, you can remove the assumption on S and allow yourself more general complexes, see 7.4.9 of the refered book. Sorry for the tangents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the diagram with cartesian squares
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X\times_S Y @> \Delta >> X \times Y\\
@V \varphi V V @VV f \times g V\\
X'\times_S Y' @> \Delta' >> X' \times Y'\\
@V  V V @VV  V\\
S @>>\Delta_S > S \times S
\end{CD}
$$
In its terms the isomorphism you want to obtain can be rewritten as
$$
\mathbf{R}\varphi_* \circ \mathbf{L}\Delta^* \cong 
\mathbf{L}{\Delta'}^* \circ \mathbf{R}(f \times g)_*
$$
which holds true as soon as the top square is Tor-independent.